# Create MongoDB collection on weekly basis using Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I am working on a blog site where 5000 no of blogs will be added weekly. 
So i want to create a new mongodb collection for blog using Spring Data.

Please suggest.

Comment: Check out the docs, http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: Do you have a [specific programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? It's not clear what you need help with.